# Databricks SQLAlchemy TBLPROPERTIES

Tags: sqlalchemy, databricks

So we have a model created using SQLAlchemy and we want to deploy it on DataBricks. The table in our model has default values for the columns. How can we deploy the table using SQLAlchemy and using the TBLPROPERTIES table clause?

Answer (score 1):

### Generic TBLPROPERTIES

Immediately after creating your model, you can listen to this event and execute a modification to the created table using the `@event.listens_for()` decorator:

```py
@event.listens_for(schema.Table, "after_create")
def set_tbl_properties(target, connection, **kw):
    if connection.engine.dialect.name == "databricks":
        connection.execute(
            DDL(f"""
            ALTER TABLE {target.fullname} SET TBLPROPERTIES (
            <your generic TBLPROPERTIES>
            )""")
        )
```

### Custom TBLPROPERTIES

If you want table-dependent TBLPROPERTIES, you can modify your models by adding custom properties. This way, when you compile the table creation, you'll be able to add your TBLPROPERTIES:

```py
@compiles(schema.CreateTable, "databricks")
def compile_create_table(element, compiler, **kw):
    stmt = compiler.visit_create_table(element, **kw)
    databricks_opts = element.element.dialect_options["databricks"]
    tblproperties = databricks_opts.get("tblproperties")
    if location:
        stmt = stmt.rstrip()
        stmt = f"{stmt} \nTBLPROPERTIES '{tblproperties}'"
    return stmt
```

---

I hope this answers your question and that you'll be able to create your tables with TBLPROPERTIES.

Comment: We ended up using the later one -

@compiles(CreateTable, 'databricks')
def post_create_table_add_tbl_properties(create, compiler, **kw):
    return compiler.visit_create_table(create, **kw) + " TBLPROPERTIES('delta.feature.allowColumnDefaults' = 'supported' )"